# Can't set a static IP on virtual vmware server

Tags: networking, vmware, static-ip

I got on Ubuntu system on a VMWare server. Well, it's a virtual box image converted to VMware.

`ifconfig` is showing this:

```
ens32     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:2d:27:fe
          inet addr:172.16.194.244  Bcast:172.16.194.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe2d:27fe/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:26553 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2700 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:8277304 (8.2 MB)  TX bytes:194793 (194.7 KB)

lo        ...
```

Well, the network card is always showing "ens32", not "eth0".

In /etc/network/interface, the config

```
iface ens32 inet static
    address 172.16.194.4
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 172.16.194.5
```

won't affect. Some sources told me, I have to change the mac address of the network card, I did that, too, it's still showing `ens32`.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by editing the network settings using the desktop.

Comment: **LQ review queue reviewers**: user posting answer to his own question.  VTC question and vote answer OK, please!